# Is there a way to change a data type of a temporary column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query where in I divide 2 columns and multiply it by 100 in a new column(DeathPercentage). But this new column data type is automatically set into bigint, is there a way that i could change it to decimal?

```
SELECT location, total_deaths, population.population, (total_deaths/population.population)*100 as DeathPercentage FROM covid_deaths
LEFT OUTER JOIN population
ON covid_deaths.location = population.country
WHERE covid_deaths.continent !='null'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres has `cast`, 2 versions. In this case you can:

```
(cast(total_deaths as numeric)/population.population)*100
                 OR
(total_deaths::numeric/population.population)*100
```

The first using the SQL standard and the second a Postgres extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
cast((total_deaths/population.population)*100) as numeric
```

Comment: You are on the right track, but your expression has 2 flaws. First the `as numeric` clause is part of the `cast` function therefore it must be inside the closing parentheses. Second, even after correcting it would fail. Without casting at least 1 of the columns the calculation would be carried out in integer arithmetic. Thus ,assuming total_deaths < population, producing 0 as a result. This result would then be cast to numeric. By casting one of the columns the calculation is carried out in real number arithmetic. See may answer below.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if your language have this, but Java have something call **casting**. That might work for your language!